# Namespace could not found on Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I want to create a cross platform application. For that, I am using Mono.

When I compile my code in Mono, I get an error: vehicleRouteCorePlanner (my dll file) could not found. But I have added that dll into my project.

[image]

error in line 2 and 3

[image]

It is running fine when I run directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: Try `mcs -r:YourDllName.dll VehicleRoutingConsome.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the "copy local" property of dll to true before compiling